# Notation for kernel/conditional measure with another measure, $\int_{A} K(x, B) \, \mathrm{d}\mu(x)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, notation

Suppose we have a finite measure $\mu$ and a Markov kernel $K$.

Together, we can define a measure on products $A \times B$ via
$$
P(A \times B) = \int_{A} K(x, B) \, \mathrm{d}\mu(x). 
$$
Suppose that for all $A$, we have $K(x, A) = \nu(A)$ for $\mu$-almost every $x$. Then $P = \mu \otimes \nu$,
it is just a product measure.

In general is there a notation for something like this? Something like $\mu \otimes K$ feels a bit misleading?

Comment: the notation used by Kallenberg is $\mu \otimes  K$

Comment: $\mu\Big(\mathbb{1}_A\,( K\mathbb{1}_B)\Big)$

Comment: Are you not specifying $K(x,B)\mu(x)$ to be the disintegration of $P$ w.r.t the projection map?